# How to get 'this' value of caller function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, this

If I have a function like this:

```
function foo(_this) {
    console.log(_this);
}

function bar() {}
bar.prototype.func = function() {
    foo(this);
}

var test = new bar();
test.func();
```

then the `test` instance of `bar` gets logged.

However, for this to work I have to pass the `this` in the `bar.prototype.func` function. I was wondering whether it is possible to obtain the same `this` value *without* passing `this`.

I tried using `arguments.callee.caller`, but this returns the prototype function itself and not the `this` value inside the prototype function.

Is it possible to log the `test` instance of `bar` by only calling `foo()` in the prototype function?

Comment: No you cannot access the context of functions up the call stack. You have to pass this context along.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to pass `this` if you are already going to be creating a special purpose function for logging attached to bar's prototype? Is there a reason other than for learning purposes to use this pattern?

Comment: @TNi: It does not necessarily have a pratical purpose, but it would be useful in my scenario. I'm trying to make a multi-level for loop by just passing a function and bounds to a function, which executes the function as it would with for loops. In a regular for loop, one can access `this`, but in this way it seems like I need to pass `this` to my function.

Comment: i think your original approach is the proper one. The best practice is to pass the instance of the object to the global function.

Comment: Yes, it may have a practical use. Sometimes *you don't choose how JS call a function* (callbacks, internals, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question is 'without passing this (by any means)' then answer is **no**

value can be passed by alternative methods though. For example using **global var (within Bar class)** or session or cookies.

```
    function bar() {

      var myThis;

      function foo() {
          console.log(myThis);
      }

      bar.prototype.func = function() {

          myThis = this;
           foo();
      }
   }

   var test = new bar();
   test.func();
```

Comment: Your still passing `this` around. I find `foo.apply(this)` to be a lot cleaner / less hackish.

Comment: I'm not passing it around, but setting value to a variable that is accessible within the namespace of the Bar class. That is a good and right way to do it.

Comment: @Raynos: That's correct, but I accepted because of stating that's it not possible. That basically answers my question.

Comment: @DmitriyNaurnov your not passing it around through function arguments, your passing it around through bar local scope and it's a hack

Comment: @Raynos: I have to disagree. I recommend you to read wikipedia about what is called hack ;) Topic is closed.

Comment: @Dmitriy Naumov *topic is closed* - so you're the authority, and everone else shut up?

Answer (score 1):

I think calling `foo` within the context of `bar` should work:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this.testVal);
}

function bar() { this.testVal = 'From bar with love'; }
bar.prototype.func = function() {
    foo.call(this);
}

var test = new bar();
test.func(); //=> 'From bar with love'
```

Comment: Thanks but I still need to pass the `this` value. What I mean is that I should be able to obtain `this` inside `foo`, by just calling `foo()` inside `func`.

Comment: But ehr, that's what happens here, or did I misunderstood your question? Calling foo like in my answer makes `this` from instance `test` available to foo, as is demonstrated by logging the testVal property of it via `log`.

Comment: I'm really sorry for not being clear. I meant obtaining the `this` of `func` within `foo` *without* actually passing `this` in `func`.

Comment: Ok, I don't really see the use of that, but hey. Actually `foo.call(this)` doesn't *pass* `this` (as you can see, `foo` has no parameters, nothing is passed), but sets the *context* of `foo` to `this`, being the instance created by the `bar` constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without changing the external function, but you must change the way you call it.

You can't get the context of the caller, but you can set the `this` property on a function you call with the method [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). See [this reference](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/) for an explanation on `this`.

```
function foo()
{
    console.log( this );
}

function bar()
{
    bar.prototype.func = function func() 
    {
        foo.apply( this );
    };
}

var test = new bar();
test.func();
```

Usually if `this` is used, it's in an object oriented context. Trying to call a method of an object with another this might indicate poor design. Explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve for more applicable design patterns.

For an example of a javascript OOP paradigm, check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358440/javascript-oop-public-and-private-variable-scope/17778023#17778023).

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
"use strict";
var o = {
    foo : function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}

function bar() {}
bar.prototype = o;
bar.prototype.constructor = bar;
bar.prototype.func = function() {
    this.foo();
}

var test = new bar();
test.func();
```

Or this:

```
"use strict";
Function.prototype.extender = function( o ){
    if(typeof o ==  'object'){
        this.prototype = o;
    }else if ( typeof o ==  'function' ) {
        this.prototype = Object.create(o.prototype);
    }else{
        throw Error('Error while extending '+this.name);
    }
    this.prototype.constructor = this;
}
var o = {
    foo : function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}

function bar() {}
bar.extender(o);
bar.prototype.func = function() {
    this.foo();
}

var test = new bar();
test.func();
```